# Electromagnetic waves phase shifting needed?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

Very simple question:

It could be observed that in electromagnetic waves we can see points when Electric and Magnetic fields waves are both in ZERO position.

Is it right?

Because of Conservation of energy I want to say that: 
When one of the wave reaches its maximum other should be in minumum.
Like in swings with potential and kinetic energy...

But here we can see that energy is forming from Nowhere...explain me please...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Thus does not violate energy conservation. Please apply energy conservation laws and show where a problem occurs.

Comment: Duplicate & links therein? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421222/104696

Comment: Two points: (1) Check the answers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/275526/are-e-and-b-fields-synchronous-in-light-waves?rq=1, (2) why QM tag?

Comment: I guess in thoose links there is an answer. Thanks.